# Mysqli en un .js

Tags: javascript, json, mysqli

Estoy haciendo un sistema de reservar online y ahora estoy en el apartado de disponibilidad, hasta ahora tengo el código en php. (Solo quiero que en un mismo dia y hora haya máximo 100 personas).
El código en php funciona perfecto, solo deja hacer reservas hasta que haya 100 personas el mismo día y hora.

Ahora quiero pasar este código php a js para hacer las comprobaciones dentro el fichero .js donde hago todas las demás comprobaciones de error, para que me salga el mensaje de error en la reserva.

```js
$('#reserves').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var nom = $.trim($("#nom").val());    
   var apellidos =$.trim($("#apellidos").val());   
   var email =$.trim($("#email").val()); 
   var telefon =$.trim($("#telefon").val()); 
   var persones =$.trim($("#persones").val()); 
   var data =$.trim($("#data").val()); 
   var hora =$.trim($("#hora").val()); 
    
   //Variables per comprovar el correu
   var expRegEmail= /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;
   var esValidEmail= expRegEmail.test(email);

   //Variables per comprovar el telefon
   var expRegTel=  /^6|7[0-9]{8}$/;
   var esValidTel= expRegTel.test(telefon);
    
   //Recuperem data d'avui
   var dataAra = new Date();
   //Convertim dataAra a String    
   var dataAraString = dataAra.getFullYear() + '-' + String(dataAra.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + String(dataAra.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');

   //Comprovar que el camp nom no estigue buit
   if(nom.length == ""){
      Swal.fire({
          type:'warning',
          title:"Ha d'ingresar un Nom",
      });
      return false; 
    }
    //Comprovar que el apellido hora no estigue buit
    if(apellidos.length == ""){
      Swal.fire({
          type:'warning',
          title:"Ha d'ingresar un Cognom",
      });
      return false; 
    }
    //Comprovar que el email hora no estigue buit
    if(email.length == ""){
      Swal.fire({
          type:'warning',
          title:"Ha d'ingresar un Correu",
      });
      return false; 
    }
    //Comprovar que el camp telefon no estigue buit
    if(telefon.length == ""){
      Swal.fire({
          type:'warning',
          title:"Ha d'ingresar un Telefon",
      });
      return false; 
    }
    //Comprovar que el camp persones no estigue buit
    if(persones.length == ""){
      Swal.fire({
          type:'warning',
          title:"Ha d'ingresar un numero de Persones",
      });
      return false; 
    }
    //Comprovar que el camp data no estigue buit
    if(data.length == ""){
      Swal.fire({
          type:'warning',
          title:"Ha d'escollir una Data per a la reserva",
      });
      return false; 
    }
    //Comprovar que el camp hora no estigue buit
    if(hora.length == ""){
      Swal.fire({
          type:'warning',
          title:"Ha d'escollir una Hora per a la reserva",
      });
      return false; 
    }
    //Comprovar el correu sigue valit
    if(esValidEmail==false){
        Swal.fire({
            type:'warning',
            title:"Correu electronic invalid",
        });
        return false;
    }
    //Comprovar el telefon sigue valit
    if(esValidTel==false){
        Swal.fire({
            type:'warning',
            title:"Telefon invalid",
        });
        return false;
    }
    //Comprovar el dia per a no realitzar una reserva un dia anterior
    if(data < dataAraString){
        Swal.fire({
            type:'warning',
            title:"Error. Dia Incorrecte",
            text: "¡Aquest dia ja ha passat!",
        });
        return false;
    }

    else{
        $.ajax({
           url:"bd/reservar.php",
           type:"POST",
           datatype: "json",
           data: {nom:nom, apellidos:apellidos, email:email, telefon:telefon, persones:persones, data:data, hora:hora}, 
           success:function(data){               
               if(data == "null"){
                   Swal.fire({
                       type:'error',
                       title:'Ups. Error al realitzar la reserva',
                   });
               }else{
                   Swal.fire({
                       type:'success',
                       title:'¡Reserva realitzada correctament, revisa el teu correu!',
                       confirmButtonColor:'#3085d6',
                       confirmButtonText:'Acceptar'
                   }).then((result) => {
                       if(result.value){
                           window.location.href = "pdf/index.php";
                       }
                   })
                   
               }
           }    
        });
    }     
});
```

```html
        //Contar numero de persones a les reserves per a aquell dia a aquella hora
        $contar_persones = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(persones) FROM reservas where data = '".$data."' and hora = '".$hora."'");
        $persones_contades = mysqli_fetch_row($contar_persones);
        
        //Maxim persones per a la mateix dia i hora
        $maxim_persones = 100;
        
        //Les persones que queden per a realitzar el ple de taules
        $resta_persones = $maxim_persones - $persones_contades[0];

        //Comprobar el numero de persones a les reserves per al dia (+persones perque al realitzar el primer insert a la base de dades no hi ha cap persona i el contador retornada 0)
        if ($persones_contades[0]+$persones <=$maxim_persones){
        }
        else{
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el JavaScript está dentro de un archivo PHP puedes asignar el valor de la variable de control mayor de 100 de forma directa.

Te explico con este ejemplo:

```
var variable_control_100 = <?php echo $Control_100; ?>
```

Donde `var variable_control_100 =` es Javascript y `<?php echo $Control_100; ?>`
es PHP

En tu validación Javascript esa variable será asignada sin problemas.

...y si lo tienes en otra página lo puedes pasar por SESSION, COOKIE, POST lo que más te convenga.

Comment: El javascript no esta dentro de un archivo php esta dentro de un .js

Comment: Si la acción se decide por la consulta en un PHP y el JS lo tienes en un archivo aparte, solo te queda hacer un fetch desde el JS al PHP y esperar la respuesta a través de una promesa. Por lo delicado de la acción NO te recomiendo una cookie para comunicarte entre esos dos lenguajes.

Comment: Lo otro que puedes hacer es diseñar ese archivo JS para que sea llamado desde un include de PHP con el código de la respuesta que te di al principio, pero solo te serviría desde PHP y no sé si tienes código reutilizable en ese JS o es solo para esa validación.